# Javascript parsing an integer from a string

Tags: javascript, parsing

What I want to do is determine if a string is numeric. I would like to know what people think about the two solutions I am trying to decide between (OR if there is a better solution that I have not found yet). The parseInt function is not suitable because it will return an integer value for a parameter like "40 years old". The two solutions I am deciding between are:

Use Integer.valueOf() with try catch

```
function isNumeric(quantity)
{
    var isNumeric = true
    try
    {
        Integer.valueOf(quantity)
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        isNumeric = false
    }
    return isNumeric
}
```

Or check each character individually

```
function IsNumeric(quantity)
{
    var validChars = "0123456789";
    var isNumber = true;
    var nextChar;

    for (i = 0; i < quantity.length && isNumber == true; i++) 
    { 
        nexChar = quantity.charAt(i); 
        if (validChars.indexOf(nextChar) == -1) 
        {
            isNumber = false;
        }
    }
    return IsNumber;
}
```

I would have thought there would be a simpler solution than both of these though. Have I just missed something?

NOTE: I am using jQuery aswel so if there is a jQuery solution that that would be sufficient

Comment: Can the string include a leading sign character (`+` or `-`)?

Comment: yes the string could be anything

Comment: `if (nexChar >= '0' && nexchar <= '9')` is more efficient than using `indexOf()`.

Comment: While Loadmaster's test is constant time compared to indexOf's O(n) (in most implementations), it does rely on the characters for digits being dense in the character set. (that is, the character symbol for "1" is one more than the symbol for '0', etc.)

Thankfully, all popular character sets (including the one specified for ECMAscript and even EBCDIC) have that property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had to do something like you want, but I needed to verify if a variable contained a number without knowing its type, it could be a numeric string (considering also exponential notation, etc.), a Number object, basically anything.

And I had to take care about implicit type conversion, for example `!isNaN(true) == true` was not good.

I ended up writing a set of 30+ unit test that you can find [here](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/35146/js/tests/isNumber.html), and I use the following function, that passes all my tests:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not `isNaN(obj)`?

```
function IsNumeric (value) {
    return (!((isNaN(value)) || (value.length == 0)));
}
```

Comment: It will fail with white-space characters also: `IsNumeric('   ') == true;` or `IsNumeric('\t \t') == true;`

Answer (score 4):

how about a regex?

```
function IsNumeric(string) { 
    return string.match(/^\d+$/) !== null;
}
```

(not tested or very defensive, but you get the point)

Comment: This will blow up if the value passed in isn't a string or worse, is null.

Comment: I'd modify the regex to allow a leading sign character: `/^[-+]?\d+$/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only testing strings, why not let any string use the method?

```
String.prototype.isNumeric= function(){
 return parseFloat(this)== this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for most values

```
function isNumericString(s)
{
   return !!s && !isNaN(+s);
}
```

generally unary + is the best way to convert to number. no base issue, no dangling non digit problem.

Comment: Will fail with white-space character strings as `isNumericString('\t \t') == true;` or `isNumericString(' ') == true;`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a regular expression to validate the input, but I honestly don't see what's wrong with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with parseInt that will work:

```
var str = "40 years old";
var isNumeric = parseInt(str) == str ? true : false;
```